# How to set offset for last carousel item in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, icarousel

I want to customise the offset of the carousel. The first carousel should start from exact below the navigation bar and last carousel should have the 0(Zero) Offset from the end of the screen.
I am using the linearType carousel.
 i am setting the following offset in viewdidload method.

```
self.carousel.contentOffset = CGSizeMake(0, (213 - self.carousel.frame.size.height) * 0.5);
```

Setting this offset increases the offset of the last carousel from bottom of the screen.

I have been trying to solve this problem from last two days but no use.

Can anybody help me to come out  from this

Any information required from my side let me know.

Answer (score -3):

use this method
'scrollToItemAtIndex:'